# Service Dependencies in NestJS

Tags: dependency-injection, service, nestjs

I have many endpoints in my app:

```
/Route1
/Route2
...
/Route99
```

In a number of these routes, there is some common functionality such as getting specific data from one source such as a local file, or another resource such as a No SQL database or external HTTP endpoint.  My problem is that these services need to have a service dependency themselves, and I am not sure that how I have currently done it is the best way to do it in NestJS.

Route1Service - Read a file of data, and return it.  This uses the FileSystemService() to wrap all the error handling, different data types, path checking etc., of the NodeJS fs module.  The Route1Service then returns this to the Route1Controller

```
@Injectable()
export class Route1Service {
    private FS_:FileSystemService; // defined here instead of constructor, as I do not know how to set it in the constructor via NestJS, or if this is even the best way.
    // constructor(private FS_: FileSystemService) { }

    // Since I do not set it in the constructor
    public DataServiceDI(FsService:FileSystemService):void {
        this.FS_ = FsService;
    }

    public GetData(): string {
        const Data:string = this.FS_.ReadLocalFile('a.txt');
        return Data;
    }
}
```

Route99Service might do the same thing, but with a different file (b.txt)

```
@Injectable()
export class Route99Service {
    private FS_:FileSystemService; 
    public DataServiceDI(FsService:FileSystemService):void {
        this.FS_ = FsService;
    }

    public GetData(): string {
        const Data:string = this.FS_.ReadLocalFile('b.txt');
        return Data;
    }
}
```

This is a contrived example to illustrate my issue.  Obviously a basic RouteService could be used, and pass the file name, but I am trying to illustrate the dependent service.  I do not know how to define the module(s) to use this dependent service or if I should be doing it this way.

What I have been doing for my definition:

```
@Module({
    controllers: [Route1Controller],
    providers: [Route1Service, FileSystemService],
})
export class Route1Module {}
```

The controller than has the constructor with both Services:

```
@Controller('route1')
export class Route1Controller 
constructor(
    private Route1_: Route1Service,
    private FsSystem_: FileSystemService
) { }
```

Now that my controller has the FsSystem service as a separate entity, I need to add a method on my Route1Service, DataServiceDI(), to allow me to pass the FileSystemService as a reference. Then my service can use this service to access the file system.

My question comes down to, is this the best practice for this sort of thing?  Ultimately, in my code, these services (FileSystemService, NoSqlService) extend a common service type, so that all my services can have this DataServiceDI() in then (they extend a base service with this definition).

Is this the best approach for longer term maintainability?  Is there an easier way to simply inject the proper service into my Route1Service so it is injected by NestJS, and I do not have to do the DI each time?

The current method works for me to be able to simply test the service, since I can easily mock the FileSystemServie, NoSqlService, etc., and then inject the mock.

Comment: Why not just have a [dynamic module](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/dynamic-modules) that's configurable, and returns the service to be injected, already with the proper configuration? That way, each route (assuming it belongs to a specific module) can just have its dependency inject the dynamic dependency from the dynamic module

Comment: I think that is what I was thinking, but I am not 100% sure how to do that. Could you show me a simple example, somewhat with my service references, as I am not following the example in NestJS (my compression, not the documentation).

Comment: @JayMcDoniel And I should then add how to test it when it is a dynamic dependency.  My biggest challenge of trying the other formats, was actually then testing the service, including mocking the dependency data.  It is simple enough to mock the GetData() to be a jest.fn().mockReturnValue('this is a.txt data') in my method, but not sure of the steps for the dynamic method either.

Comment: I think the docs link above [and this article](https://dev.to/nestjs/advanced-nestjs-how-to-build-completely-dynamic-nestjs-modules-1370) will be able to teach it more succinctly than  can

Comment: Your references certainly helped with my understanding for the dynamic modules.  I guess the part that does not flow for me though, is the decision between a.txt and b.txt is not known in the routes, it is based on data in the payload.  So a POST /route1 might specify the b.txt, and the POST /route5 might be an a.txt.  The common issue is to read that data, but it is really only known at the time of execution, not ahead of time for dynamic modules, at least by my understanding currently.

Comment: Then you'll probably need to pair it with the [`ModuleRef`](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/module-ref) and have some sort of logic that says "if receive data `x` then read file `y`" and let that change which provider you load up. I would  argue that each route should have a defined and deterministic effect, and that if the route needs to be this dynamic, the abstraction probably does not bring in the benefits it should

Comment: As an FYI. the problem is that I am trying to make a testing emulator for our team to use instead of a client web system, that may be up or down at different times.  The issue is that the endpoints I am trying to make simple replacements for, actually use the payloads received, a field in the payload indicates the operation to do (delete a record for instance) and another field for the record). As some functions we can do, I have routes for those, and others I need to understand and call different sources for information (text files, HTTP etc.).